# I had seriously considered telling the story from the point of view of the wives

Tags: grammar, double-possessives

> I had seriously considered telling the story from the point of view of the wives.

the point of view of the wives or

the point of view of the wives'

Which one is appropriate in terms of grammar or idiommatic expression?

For your info, in case of a friend of 'mine', a frined of 'hers'
possessive pronouns are positioned after the preposition 'of'.

Answer (score 2):

Use "wives", without an apostrophe.

The use of "friend of mine" is a little hangover from when English had a genitive case. Modern English doesn't have it, though the possessive does act in a similar way.

Here, a possessive is not needed, so leave it out.